# Node-mysql не работает со строчными значениями

Tags: mysql, node.js

Нужно выбрать строку из бд, если использовать производить выборку по числовому столбцу то все прекрасно работает, но если по столбцу со строкой то возвращается пустой результат и никаких ошибок. SQL в phpmyadmin на сервере прекрасно работает.
Код (делал специально чтоб проверить работает ли):

```
con.query("SELECT unit FROM `units_info` WHERE `name`=?",[match[1]],function (error,row){
  console.log('errors:'+error);
  console.log(row)});
```

Match[1] - строковая переменная, результат обработки строки введённой пользователем по регулярному выражению.

Даже если вместо `name`=? ввести `name`='Текст' то не работает (хотя напрямую в phpmyadmin прекрасно обрабатывается)

Comment: Ну если ошибок нет, то смотрите в таблице строку со значением match[1] и чему равно match[1] в момент запроса.

Comment: На всякий случай - а если ``"SELECT unit FROM `units_info` WHERE `name`='?' "``...

Comment: Взял место куда должна подставляться переменная (знак вопроса) в одинарные ковычки не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось проще чем я думал, ошибка была в кодировке!